# SSD vs SATA Drive

Tags: ssd, performance, sata

By how much the processing time of macbook pro changes by changing sata drive to ssd? If it makes much difference then which ssd will be best? I was thinking of changing by current SATA drive but I want to first get sure that after changing I will get a considerable change in performance of my Mac. I used a MacBook air and was stunned by its performance. The only difference between my MacBook pro and air was of hard drive. I searched google about it but didn't got any good answer about it.

Comment: Please modify your question for which product to buy.  This isn't a tech support forum.  Your question will be closed by the mods.  Just giving you fair warning. Please post to the superuser stackexchange if this question doesn't already exist there.